# How Do I Use/Import my Java Locale class and Resource Bundle properties to be used in my HTML files (not JSP)?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internationalization, resourcebundle

For my current project, I have a Spring Boot REST service backend using JSON and a set of asynchronous HTML files for the frontend accessing the REST service using AJAX. I want to use my Java localization class and my resource bundle properties file for the languages I need which I had created and it worked fine for my previous projects which only used JSP pages.

However, for my new project, I am using purely asynchronous HTML files with AJAX (jQuery and vanilla Javascript) and no JSP front-end to connect to my Java backend. So how do I import and use my Java i18N features in my purely HTML files with AJAX without any JSP?

Comment: Not sure whether the solution is different here but in general you would set a cookie to store the chosen language, and this cookie is then passed along with every AJAX request. Thus the server can read it and reply with the respective language. What you definitely cannot do is "import my Java i18N features in purely HTML files"

Comment: Maybe create a ResponseBody object which sorts of read a key string and return the corresponding language string from the correct resource bundle file? But this is all already automated and taken care of in Java internationalization and if I use JSP which I'm not. What is the standard way of doing multilingual apps in today's modern way like AJAX/HTML or React/Angular?

Comment: Again: can't you simply read a cookie and send back the appropriate language as described [here](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/internationalization-basic-jsp-servlet/#33_Using_Browser_Cookie_As_Locale)? I've never used JSP but why is i18n suddenly a huge problem just because you're sending back JSON instead of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `Java` code in `HTML` file. The way it works with `JSP` is because `JSP` simply gets compiled to `Java Servlets` while compilation stage and then they run. The best bet to make it work with HTML along with Ajax is, create some kind of meta controller, which provides you the required data related to localization and internationalization in response, and then use it with `JavaScript`.

Comment: Is there any way to continue to use the internationalization and locale features in Java in the modern asynchronous HTML and Javascript (eg. React, Angular) files of today? I know there is the lang metatag for HTML but that does not have anything to do with resource bundles and locale in Java. Or do I have to ditch all my resource bundle properties file and Locale class in Java and do it a new way? What is the standard way for multilingual features for say AJAX or React/Angular?

Comment: I guess another way is to maybe use  a Map with key and value pairs and just modify my resource bundle properties file so that one is a key and the other is a value! But I wonder how programmers nowadays are doing multilingual apps with HTML/AJAX and React/Angular stuff?

Comment: I am not very much familiar with localization with React/Angular, but you can check this link for Angular localization - https://angular.io/guide/i18n. If you are working these technologies (APIs for backend and React/Angular for frontend), then ideally your frontend should not be dependent on your backend for localization stuff.

Comment: And if you want to continue using your resource bundle files, then you can create an API, which in response will provide the data of resource bundle in JSON format and you can use this API to get localization related stuff from backend and use it in frontend.

Comment: Yes Jignesh, I have  just seen YouTubes on React and Angular internationalization and they use JSON-based key-value json files for each language (e.g. en.json, ja.json, etc) so its just a global search-and-replace for my Java i18N resource bundles I guess. Just thinking.. how do I do the internationalization (match the key and fetch the matching language string) on the FRONT end rather than BACK end if I am just using plain HTML files and AJAX (no React or Angular) ? It would  save a round trip to the server!